# OracleWebRowSet cannot be cast to CachedRowSetImpl when calling acceptChanges()

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jdbc, resultset

Tried using `OracleWebRowset` to export and import `ResultSet` objects.

refer "https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/jcrowset.htm#BABCFJBE"

```
OracleWebRowSet rs = new OracleWebRowSet();
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory","oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory");
FileReader fReader = new FileReader("xmlfile.xml");
rs.readXml(fReader);
rs.acceptChanges();
rs.close();
```

This raises the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleWebRowSet cannot be cast to com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl
    at com.sun.rowset.internal.CachedRowSetWriter.writeData(CachedRowSetWriter.java:275)
    at oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet.acceptChanges(OracleCachedRowSet.java:1776)
```

Tried casting the basic `WebRowSetImpl()` to no avail

the reason I couldn't use the basic `WebRowSet` is because oracle `NVARCHAR2` columns poses issues while writing and reading XML, raised errors like "can't form insert statements" and "not a proper type"

is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution...

Seems that the rowset writer and reader are not set properly in the `OracleCachedRowSet` base class of `OracleWebRowSet`

So to fix the issue, include two lines of code before calling `acceptchanges()` method

```
rs.setReader(new OracleCachedRowSetReader());
rs.setWriter(new OracleCachedRowSetWriter());
```

So the fixed code would look like:

```
OracleWebRowSet rs = new OracleWebRowSet();
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory","oracle.xml.jaxp.JXSAXParserFactory");
FileReader fReader = new FileReader("xmlfile.xml");
rs.readXml(fReader);
rs.setReader(new OracleCachedRowSetReader());
rs.setWriter(new OracleCachedRowSetWriter());
rs.acceptChanges();
rs.close();
```